# How to set google protobuf repeated field in java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Here is my definition

```
message point{
  optional float x = 1;
  optional float y = 2;
}
message test{
  repeated field point = 1;
}
```

In my `example.java` file I am trying to create a builder as follows:

```
for(i = 0; i < somearr.size(); i++)
{
    // I get x and y values from traversing the array 
    float x = getX;
    float y = getY;

    // now I want to set the repeated field point
}
```

How do I set the repeated field points?

Answer (score 10):

Very similar to `repeated PhoneNumber` example [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial).

Capitalizing those messages will help code readability.

```
message Point {
  optional float x = 1;
  optional float y = 2;
}
message Test {
  repeated Point point = 1;
}
```

java:

```
Test.Builder b = Test.newBuilder();

for (i = 0; i < somearr.size(); i++) {
    float x = getX; // somehow?
    float y = getY; // ??
    b.addPoint(Point.newBuilder().setX(x).setY(y).build());
}

Test mytest = b.build();
```

Answer (score 8):

```
List<Point> points = ...;
Test.newBuilder().addAllPoint(points);
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.