# Swift - Crash when adding phrases in speech context array

Tags: swift, swift3, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

As per the best practices, below information are suggested in the [google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics).

“The Cloud Speech API includes a very large vocabulary. However, if proper names or domain-specific words are out-of-vocabulary, you can add them to the phrases provided to your requests's speechContext.”

So, I added phrases in speechContextsArray like below in [google sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Swift/Speech-gRPC-Streaming):

```
let recognitionConfig = RecognitionConfig()
recognitionConfig.encoding =  .linear16
recognitionConfig.sampleRateHertz = Int32(sampleRate)
recognitionConfig.languageCode = "en-US"
recognitionConfig.maxAlternatives = 0
recognitionConfig.enableWordTimeOffsets = false

// My line:
recognitionConfig.speechContextsArray = [["phrases": ["BalaKrishnan", "Liu Xiang", "Tirupati", "Pushpanathan", "Ashraf"]]]
```

But I faced run time issue when tap start streaming button from sample app:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtGCs26_SwiftDeferredNSDictionarySSGSaSS__ isInitialized]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000023c3a0'

when reading below line:

```
let streamingRecognizeRequest = StreamingRecognizeRequest()
streamingRecognizeRequest.audioContent = audioData as Data // crash here - on run time
```

What should I do now? Am going to implement the voice to text feature for searching persons names in database. So, my inputs always be any persons names from any languages. So, please give solution for how to add phrases. And also suggest any other voice to text best services.

Comment: First try to add proper quotes around Ashraf

Comment: It seems like it has to do with selectors in 
 swift3 like in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344184/swift-3-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-xcode-8). Chances are the code in example is older then swift3?

Comment: @A.Queue No! Code is working fine if i didn't add that phrase line...

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev  
Its happened when am copying code to textedit. That is not problem. Crash is happening in another line which i shown in question.

Comment: Right. I don't know how proto files work/integrate with swift, but it seems like in proto file the `speechContextsArray` is [defined differently](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/blob/7bd30ccee251408e11929e4074ed6031e7b8f4fe/speech/Objective-C/Speech-gRPC-Streaming/google/cloud/speech/v1/cloud_speech.proto#L204). So I am not sure if it assumes this notation: https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf#quick-start https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081493/how-to-set-google-protobuf-repeated-field-in-java

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue but then noticed `recognitionConfig.speechContextsArray`requires an array of `speechContext`, not the phrases itself.

Here's my solution:

```
var phraseHints : NSMutableArray = ["one", "two", "three"]
let speechContext = SpeechContext()
speechContext.phrasesArray = phraseHints
recognitionConfig.speechContextsArray = [speechContext]
```

Comment: I'll try it soon